# Devise authentication on Ruby on Rails, don't use password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it possible to have Devise not worry about passwords at all? I am experimenting with it in a Rails app that will use only OpenID for authentication and nothing else. I don't want to store anything related to passwords in my database. Does Devise *have* to use passwords or is there a way to configure so it doesn't have to worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

devise module Database Authenticatable. as github says its responsible for

> Database Authenticatable: encrypts and
>   stores a password in the database to
>   validate the authenticity of a user
>   while signing in. The authentication
>   can be done both through POST requests
>   or HTTP Basic Authentication.

Maybe you want to not include this module in you User model.
Also im guess if you dont want to store password, than creating your own registration/authentication process is a great idea. See Ryan [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication) about it, should be enough, just cut the part with password.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. I'm not sure if it requires passwords or not. I don't have experience with this myself.

https://github.com/nbudin/devise_openid_authenticatable